# Vagrant synced folder link to Apache /var/www/ in Ubuntu VM

Tags: windows, apache, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm not sure how to phrase the title; hopefully, it made sense. I am learning about Vagrant and just found out about synced folders. I am doing web development and want to edit/create my files and folders on my local machine instead of Ubuntu 14.04 (on Vagrant).

I store my files in my `/vagrant/` folder, which end up appearing on both machines. This is perfect. I want these folders/files to be automatically moved to `/var/www/` as soon as a file or folder is changed in the synced folder.

For example:

- Make folder on Windows 10 called `test` inside the synced folder. Put `index.html` inside `test`.
- The folder and file are uploaded to the Ubuntu machine.
- Inside of `/var/www/` in the Ubuntu machine, there should be a copy of the `test` folder along with all the files inside of it.
- The `test` folder inside `/var/www/` updates if any changes are made in the synced folder `/vagrant/`.

I was looking into the `ln` command but I keep getting an error saying "hard links not allowed". I was trying like this on Ubuntu:

```
cd /vagrant
ln test /var/www/
```

Should I approach this differently? How can I accomplish what I want to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've started learning about Vagrant some days ago, too. I'm planning to use it with **Ruby**. Luckly, I found out that [RubyMine seems to support Vagrant natively natively](https://jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/vagrant.html). So maybe in your programming language of choice, you find an IDE that supports Vagrant, too. E.g. for **PHP** there is [PhpStorm that also seems to support Vagrant](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+started+with+Vagrant+in+PhpStorm). For **Python** you can use [PyCharm with Vagrant support](https://jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/vagrant.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing development in PHP so I'll look into PhpStorm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do *sharing folder* using vagrant, it is called [*synced folder*](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) in Vagrant terminology

If you want to sync the guest `/var/www` you can add the following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "www/", "/var/www"
```

so if you create the `www/` folder within your local/host project folder, any files that you will save under this www folder will automatically be synchronized with the `/var/www` folder of your ubuntu machine

vagrant/virtualbox do not really limit you in the number of sync folder so you should adopt that rather than using one and work with symlink.

Comment: Oh, this is so much better than using symlinks. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Another way of syncing your folder is to create a soft link in linux. Just type this into your command line:

rm -rf /var/www

ln -fs /vagrant /var/www

This will remove the /var/www folder and create a soft link so that whoever tries to go to /var/www will be automatically be redirected to your synced folder which in this case is /vagrant but you can change that to something different.

you can also create a shell script for this so that every time you create a virtual instance, it can automatically do this for you instead of you having to manually do it every time.

Here is a link to how to make the vagrant file run a shell script when you vagrant up:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html